# How can i get only part of this string?

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to create an little database of some TV shows, They are usually named like this:

**Show.Name.S01E01.Episode Name**

OR

**Show.Name.S01E01.Some.Stuff.Here.Episode Name**

How can i get Just the Show Name and season & episode number so i'm left with the following:

**Show.Name.S01E01**

I've tried using the following but it dosen't work as some shows have . in them,

```
explode(".", "Show.Name.S01E01.Some.Stuff.Here.Episode Name");
```

Thanks

Comment: Can there be a `.` in your _Show Name_? If not, you can use `explode()`

Comment: Usually by writing some code. Have you tried anything?

Comment: If there aren't periods in show names, you could split on `.` and use only the first two array parts. Otherwise you might need a regex to determine the season/episode section backtrack to the show name from there.

Comment: @AD7six - I don't care.

Comment: @AD7six If i could of written the code i would of, hence why i posted on a coding help site. Now ive been shown explode i can research it.

Comment: @Exoon there's a big difference to the SO community between "I want to do x _, I've read this, found that, tried this, this and that but it doesn't work_" and "give me code to do x".

Comment: @AD7six, I understand what your'e saying but i'm not really sure how else it could of been asked, I didn't know how to do something so i asked on a help site and got an answer so isn't that the whole point of SO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would return you what you want:

```
<?php
function getShowInfo($str) {
  if (preg_match('/^(.+?)\.S(\d+)E(\d+)(?:.+?)?\.[^.]+$/',$str, $m))
    return $m;
  return null;
}

print_r(getShowInfo('Show Name.S01E02.Episode Name'));
print_r(getShowInfo('Show Name.S01E02.Some.Stuff.Here.Episode Name'));
```

Example output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Show Name.S01E02.Episode Name
    [1] => Show Name
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 02
)
Array
(
    [0] => Show Name.S01E02.Some.Stuff.Here.Episode Name
    [1] => Show Name
    [2] => 01
    [3] => 02
)
```

Comment: Hmm but he wants the `Show Name.S01E02`. Maybe you could do this, target `S`with two numbers next and then `E` with two numbers next, that's the most common format. It means Season 01 Episode 02 etc. So you might want to extract all the text till there.

Comment: This is perfect thanks so much. The explode solution weren't working as alot of shows had . in them.

Answer (score 1):

use [explode()](http://www.php.net/explode)

```
$Parts = explode('.','Show Name.S01E01.Episode Name');
echo $Parts[0].'.'.$Parts[1];
```

output

```
Show Name.S01E01
```

alternative with [list()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list($ShowName, $EpisodeCode, $EpisodeName) = explode('.','Show Name.S01E01.Episode Name');
echo $ShowName.'.'.$EpisodeCode;
```

output

```
Show Name.S01E01
```

be careful, the name of the show or the episode title may contain additional dots that might give you problems

Comment: It's by the way also a great use case for `list()`

Comment: @bwoebi +1 it is a good idea

Comment: Since the OP is new to explode(), maybe you could add in some description of what it does and a reference link :)

Comment: -1. I don't see why you would give an answer that you know would give unexpected output on certain strings. Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D would disapprove.

Comment: Yeah i'm having issues with this as the show names are like Show.Name.S01.E01.

Comment: @Adrian I suggested a solution, warning of possible problems.